# Can the sum of odd divisors of an integer exceed n

Tags: divisor-sum

I know that the sum of divisors of an integer n can exceed it (abundant numbers) but can this occur when only considering odd divisors of n? Can the sum of all integers j : j|n, 2∤j be greater than n? If not how is it proven, and if so what is an example?

Comment: [Wikipedia has the answer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number#Properties)

Comment: Hint: Try  to consider Odd numbers. Maybe proper divisors?

Comment: Since the sum of reciprocals of odd numbers diverge to infinity, the answer is yes.